# KeyPressEvent doesn't trigger when pressing Enter/Return in ComboBox

Tags: c#, keypress

I have some Problems getting the KeyPressEvent on the Return/Enter Key when my Combobox is selected... With a TextBox however it worked just fine.. But thats not what i need right now! Other Keys (like Space or some letters) DO work in my ComboBox.

It may be important, that I set the DropDownStyle to DropDown, the AutocompleteMode to SuggestAppend and the AutoCompleteSource to ListItems..

I already tried something like this:

```
  private void cbItem_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(e.ToString());

        if (e.KeyChar == (char)Keys.Return)
        {
            txtUrl.Text = mainUrl + changeName(cbItem.SelectedItem.ToString());

            string htmlCode = client.DownloadString(txtUrl.Text.ToString());

            MessageBox.Show(htmlCode);

            e.Handled = true;
        }
```

Hope You can give me some advice! :)

Comment: Sure, use KeyDown instead.  Also make sure the form does not have the AcceptButton property set.  And beware that your user will never figure out by himself that pressing the key might be useful.

Comment: Ohh wow that fixed it... Thanks alot!! Small things can change like everything